# Upload files as a user that only has git-shell

Tags: bash, git, scp, git-shell

I have a user on my server that has `/usr/bin/git-shell` in `/etc/passwd`.

How do I upload files to the folder `~/www/` on the server, where I have owner rights?

If I try scp, I get this error:

```
$ scp index.html gituser@example.de:~/www/
fatal: unrecognized command 'scp -t ~/www/'
lost connection
```

Comment: Try `git scp`.  Note that `git-shell` only "permits execution only of server-side Git commands implementing the pull/push functionality, plus custom commands present in a subdirectory named git-shell-commands in the user’s home directory."

Answer (score 0):

### scp with git-shell

It possible to allow usage of `scp` with `git-shell` by
creating the following `scp` executable file in `git-shell-commands` in the remote user home directory:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

exec /usr/bin/scp "$@"
```

For example, it is done in the [frugalware git-hooks repo](https://github.com/frugalware/git-hooks/blob/master/git-shell-commands/scp).

The file can be also customized to allow usage of `scp` only for certain conditions, for example, for specific public keys.

### Details

It works because a local `scp` call executes the remote `scp` ssh command with `-t` or `-f` argument. The protocol is explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/50644600/4023446

When `git-shell` is used it allows only commands in the directory `git-shell-commands`. So, the above script is executed during remote scp sessions launching the actual `/usr/bin/scp` binary.